# Displaying alert in Swift shows UICollectionViewCell warning

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm pretty new to Swift and I'm having some trouble implementing alerts into my SpriteKit game. The below code works on device & emulator, however every time I run the code I get warnings.

GameViewController.swift:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    
    let scene = SceneMenu(size: view.frame.size)
    scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
    scene.backgroundColor = .white
    
    let view = view as! SKView
    view.presentScene(scene)
    
}

}
```

SceneMenu.swift:

```
import SpriteKit

class SceneMenu: SKScene {

override init(size: CGSize) {
    
    super.init(size: size)
    
    let btnAlert = SKLabelNode(text: "Show Alert")
    btnAlert.name = "btn_alert"
    btnAlert.fontSize = 20
    btnAlert.fontColor = SKColor.blue
    btnAlert.fontName = "Avenir"
    btnAlert.position = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2, y: size.height / 2)
    addChild(btnAlert)
    
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    
}

func showAlert() {
    
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "message", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
    
    alert.addTextField { field in
        field.placeholder = "Type your name"
    }
    
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { _ in
        print("OK")
    })
    
    view?.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true)
    
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    
    if let touch = touches.first {
        
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        let action = atPoint(location)
        
        if action.name == "btn_alert" {
            
            showAlert()
            
        }
        
    }
    
}

}
```

Debug warning #1 (not sure why I am getting this? As you can see from the code, I'm not using UICollectionViewCell):

> 2022-06-04 15:31:46.134563+0100 Game16[86767:3617120] [LayoutConstraints] Changing the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property of a UICollectionViewCell that is managed by a UICollectionView is not supported, and will result in incorrect self-sizing. View: <_UIAlertControllerTextFieldViewCollectionCell: 0x122022da0; frame = (0 0; 270 24); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600000a97e40>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000498220>>

Debug warning #2 (displayed only in emulator and could be ignored - I was told so):

> 2022-06-04 15:32:10.228624+0100 Game16[86767:3617120] [HardwareKeyboard] -[UIApplication getKeyboardDevicePropertiesForSenderID:shouldUpdate:usingSyntheticEvent:], failed to fetch device property for senderID (778835616971358211) use primary keyboard info instead.

Any help would be appreciated. thanks.